# Reading special characters like ρ,λ from word using interop word library of visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am reading a word file using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document` library of visual studio.The problem is the file contain special characters like  **ρ,λ** .And when i read in C# they are converted in **?** Question mark .
For example i am reading a line like 
    `A child drinks a liquid of density ρ through a vertical straw.`

So this line is converted into `A child drinks a liquid of density ? through a vertical straw.`
So please help me how they are preserved in their original form.

Here is the code

```
   public void ReadMsWord()
    {
        // variable to store file path
        string filePath = null;
        // open dialog box to select file
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        // dilog box title name
        file.Title = "Word File";
        // set initial directory of computer system
        file.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        // set restore directory
        file.RestoreDirectory = true;

        // execute if block when dialog result box click ok button
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // store selected file path
            filePath = file.FileName.ToString();
        }
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
        // create object of missing value
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // create object of selected file path
        object path = filePath;
        // set file path mode
        object readOnly = false;
        // open document                
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref   
        miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,  
        ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        try
        {

            // create word application


            // select whole data from active window document
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            // handover the data to cllipboard
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            // clipboard create reference of idataobject interface which transfer the 
            data
            IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            //set data into richtextbox control in text format
            string  t = "";
            string[] y = {};
            t = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
            string[] options = { };
            y = t.Split('\n');
           }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
              throw ex;
    }
          }
```

Comment: Your problem may have to do with text encoding. For faster help, please provide your code.

Comment: @mortb wait i am  sharing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
t = data.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText).ToString();
```

i.e. `UnicodeText` instead of `Text`. Please note that special characters will still be displayed as `?` in a console window, but they are shown correctly in e.g. MessageBox.Show or the debugger.

Comment: Yes, the characters also have to be part of the font used to display them to show correctly.

Comment: OK, and if you change `Text` to `UnicodeText` in your code, it works or it does not work?

Comment: Thanks for so rapid reply @Martin .